# Need help understanding a specific part in a proof concerning abundant numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Theorem:
*The product of two primes is not abundant*

Proof:

Assume $n=p_1p_2$, where $p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{P}$

Assume that $2\leq p_1,3\leq p_2$

Note that $\frac{p_1+1}{p_1-1}$ is a decreasing function of $p_1$ (*Why did the mathematician choose this function?, why did it have to be decreasing?*).

So,  $\max\left \{ \frac{p_1+1}{p_1-1} \right \}=3$.

Hence,
$\max\left \{ \frac{p_1+1}{p_1-1} \right \}=3\leq p_2$.

With some algebraic manipulation we get,

$\max\left \{ \frac{p_1+1}{p_1-1} \right \}\leq p_2$, and
$1+p_1+p_2\leq p_2p_1\leq 2p_1p_2$.

*Could anyone explain this proof/clarify?. I understand up until the last line. Does the proof imply that the sum of primes is always bounded below their even product?*

Comment: My mistake, I corrected it. It should read,  $\frac{p_1-1}{p_1+1}$. This is the function I'm using.

Comment: I understand, Is there a specific reason though that a decreasing function had to be used to arrive at this inequality? I'm a bit new to analysis.

Comment: I corrected it, I just accidentally put the -,+ in the wrong place. My mistake.

Comment: @John Any further question concerning the proof ? I edited the boldface, that was too bold.

Comment: The last line (though correct as written) is missing something.  You have proved $1+p_1+p_2 \le p_1p_2$.  While it is true that $p_1p_2 \le 2p_1p_2$, what you want to say is the sum of divisors of $n$ is $1+p_1+p_2 + p_1p_2$, which is less than $2n$ and you need a less than somewhere, not less than or equal everywhere.

Comment: If you want some examples of abundant numbers, look [here](https://oeis.org/A005101).

Comment: @dietrich After looking through all the responses I think I understand now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

An integer $n$ is called abundant, if $\sigma(n)>2n$. For $n=p_1p_2$, this gives
$$
1+p_1+p_2+p_1p_2=\sigma(n)>2n=2p_1p_2.
$$
Your argument shows that $1+p_1+p_2\le p_1p_2$, so that the inequality does not hold, and hence that $n$ is not abundant. The decreasing function is "designed" to derive this inequality. We need that $\frac{p_1+1}{p_1-1}\le p_2$.